# Is there a required method for creating Computer records in AD DS when replacing a PDC?

Tags: active-directory, windows-server-2012-r2

Server 2012 R2, Win 8/8.1

I experienced a total failure of my PDC, and in the process of trying to move the operations master role over to the secondary DC I messed it up as well; bummer.  Fortunately it's currently a very small system and learning in this environment is accepted.

So I've created a new PDC and have added the Users.  But when it comes to the Computers I'm curious if it matters how those records are created. Sometimes there are automatic processes run by the system in the background that are important.

Can I manually create the records, or do I need to let that happen during a 'join to the domain'?

**If the answer is 'join to the domain' then I have a follow-on question:**  Each of the computers were already joined to the domain, so when I navigate Control Panel > System > Change Settings > Change, the computer is already a Member of the domain.  So the only way to force the join is to revert to a Workgroup, and then join the domain again.  That appears to work, but is this much work really necessary?

Thanks.

Comment: `do I need to let that happen during a join to the domain?` - Short and sweet: the computers need to join the new domain. `is this much work really necessary?` - you can simply type the new domain name (providing that each computer is using the correct AD DNS server) and provide the appropriate username and password when prompted.

Comment: I'm guessing I didn't communicate clearly, I'm sorry.  When I type in the domain name, it's not new because that PC was already a member when I had to kill the PDC & 2nd DC, therefore the OS won't actually 'do a join'; kind of like a politician we all know of, I have to leave the domain to join the domain.  I can do that, but I just wondered if manually adding the Computer in AD DS accomplishes the same thing, or will there be missing pieces inside AD DS doing it that way?  (BTW, crabbygeezer.com doesn't load up - is it still valid?)

Comment: No, the fact that the new domain has the same name as the old domain is irrelevant. The computers are joined to the old domain, they need to be joined to the new domain. In your case, because the domain name is the same, you'll probably have to put the computers in workgroup mode, reboot and join the new domain.

Comment: Glad to help...